# Using the four color theorem to check if a graph is Planar

Tags: graph-theory

I've just learned about the four color theorem. So my question is: "Given an undirected graph if I am able to color this undirected graph with 1,2,3 or at most colors 4 colors such that no two vertices with the same colors are adjacent, can I by the four color theorem conclude that the graph is a planar graph"?

Comment: There is a test for planarity given by Kuratowski's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)

Comment: Thanks I assume that is the to-go theorem if you want to disprove planarity. I looked up the definition of a subdivision which states that - In a graph $G$, subdivision of an edge $uv$ is the operation of replacing $uv$ with a path $u,w,v$ through a new vertex $w$. I suppose that means we're allowed to add an extra vertex to an already given path on $G$ and maybe also remove? But we are not allowed to add or remove edges in a subdivision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The four-colour theorem only stats that if a graph is planar then it can be coloured by at most four colours. It does not state the converse, and indeed $K_{3,3}$ is bipartite – can be coloured with only two colours – but is not planar.

Comment: You were 15 seconds ahead of me, +1 :)